# Setting up Keycloak for a company with multiple subsidiaries, each with separate services

Tags: keycloak, multi-tenant

I'm trying to set up Keycloak as a Single Sign-On solution for my company, which consists of several subsidiaries. Each subsidiary has its own services, and not all services share the same users. My initial idea was to configure each subsidiary as a realm and its services as clients. However, I'm finding it challenging to set up the users as they are not necessarily shared among all services within a subsidiary. How can I set this up in Keycloak? Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

I initially tried to set up each subsidiary as a separate realm in Keycloak, and each service as a client within the corresponding realm. I expected this setup to allow me to manage users within each realm separately, and grant them access to different services (clients) within their own realm. However, this approach did not work as I anticipated because users are managed at the realm level, not at the client level. I found that all users within a realm have potential access to all clients within that realm, but I need to further restrict access to different clients to different subsets of users within the same realm.